# Replaying pcap on loopback

Tags: pcap, loopback, tcpdump, tcpreplay

I have a set of `pcap` files containing UDP traffic from two hosts, and have to perform some analysis on this traffic on a regular basis.

Ideally, I would want to avoid having to frequently setup local interfaces with specific IPs and such to replay these files. I want to be able to simply replay them on my loopback interface, using `tcprewrite` to change the `pcap`.

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
# Remove mac addresses for loopback interface
# Remove VLAN tags
tcprewrite \
  --enet-smac=00:00:00:00:00:00 \
  --enet-dmac=00:00:00:00:00:00 \
  --enet-vlan=del \
  --infile="${INFILE}" \
  --outfile="${OUTFILE}.tmp"

# Change source and destination IP to loopback
# Regenerate IP checksums
tcprewrite \
  --srcipmap=0.0.0.0/0:127.0.0.1 \
  --dstipmap=0.0.0.0/0:127.0.0.1 \
  --fixcsum \
  --infile="${OUTFILE}.tmp" \
  --outfile="${OUTFILE}"
```

It seems to almost work. I can then simply replay these files on my loopback using `tcpreplay` and I see the packets using `tcpdump` on `lo`. Still, it seems that any regular userspace socket does not see this traffic on the loopback.

From my understanding, it seems to be related to the way layer 2 is handled on the loopback interface on linux. It would seem I need to rewrite the layer 2 headers (DLT) from plain `ethernet` to the `null` protocol used by BSD loopbacks.

Anyone having experience on replaying UDP traffic captured on ethernet to the loopback interface would be greatly appreciated. I cannot figure out how, or whether this is at all possible with `pcap`/`tcprewrite`.

I tried to follow https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html and force a DLT header type of `0` (DLT_NULL) and content of `2` (IPv4) but with no success:

```
tcprewrite \
  --enet-smac=00:00:00:00:00:00 \
  --enet-dmac=00:00:00:00:00:00 \
  --enet-vlan=del \
  --dlt=user \
  --user-dlt=0 \
  --user-dlink=02,00,00,00 \
  --infile="${INFILE}" \
  --outfile="${OUTFILE}.tmp"
```

```
Fatal Error in tcpedit.c:tcpedit_packet() line 135:
 From plugins/dlt_null/null.c:dlt_null_encode() line 201:
DLT_NULL and DLT_LOOP plugins do not support packet encoding
```